# Unityでの親子関係について

Tags: unity3d

unityの親子関係について質問です。

親の回転の影響を子が受けないようにできるのは調べたところわかったのですが
逆に子だけ回転させて、その影響を親が受けないようにすることは可能ですか？

もし可能であればその際に使用する関数なども教えていただけると幸いです。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 親、子、影響というのがどういう意図なのかはわかりませんが、もともと子の移動や回転は親には影響を与えません。どういう意図で「影響を与える」「影響を与えない」と言っているかもう少し詳しくお願いします。

Comment: すいません、何とか自力で解決できました。